# c# fix pointer after initialization

Tags: c#, pointers

I'm trying to understand how to use pointers with C#. I have:

```
unsafe public class Actionable
{
    public Vector3* aim;
}
```

and:

```
unsafe public class Ship : Actionable
{
    public Ship()
    {
        // generates error: cannot use the fixed statement to take the address
        // of an already fixed expression
        fixed(aim = &(gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().localEulerAngles));

        // generates error: Cannot take the address of the given expression
        aim = &(gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().localEulerAngles);

        // works fine (apparently)
        *aim = gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().localEulerAngles;
    }
}
```

**Question 1:** As per [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx) and other sources on the web, what `unsafe`does is merely mark the code between curlies as needing a special attention for programmers and in an example code `fixed` is explicitly used inside an `unsafe` scope. Then why do I get the error

> cannot use the fixed statement to take the address of an already fixed
>   expression

After searching for the error on WWW I found [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9beaw6ss.aspx) which states that `unsafe` automatically pins (fixes?) the address of the pointee. And at times I got an error stating "

> Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context

I'm confused.

**Question 2:** Why `*aim = (...)` works but `aim = &(...)` doesn't (since it's fixed)?
And if you wonder why do I need pointers the answer is
A. Readability.  I would have used an alias (ref from C++) but C# misses it. Or a the #define from C++ but again, C# doesn't have it.
B. Bypassing the unnecessary execution, since it's only a matter of accessing a variable,  <strike>not of executing (hidden or otherwise) routines or methods.</strike> I found out that the variable I'm trying to access is in fact a property.
EDIT:
It looks like just dereferencing doesn't help, I need access to the memory address.

Comment: My biggest advice for using pointers in C# would be: *don't*. I would highly recommend considering an alternate solution for C# code.

Comment: @E.Moffat: Why everytime a user askes about how a feature works they are replied to: "better don't use it"? Many great ingenious languages features were prohibited and abandoned just because some dumb programmers used it wrong? I always said: better prohibit knives and even cars since fatal accidents happen all the time.

Comment: @E.Moffat: sorry, I'm frustrated that I'm forced to resort to pointers, and this in a way more complicated fashion compared to C++, instead of  being able to simply assign a macro or a reference (alias) for some variable, cause this is precisely my use case.

Comment: exactly why I didn't answer the question as asked, and added a comment instead. I don't think pointers are an ingenious language feature, they're a backwards compatibility thing from to help C or C++ programmers transition to C#. I don't think you're as 'forced to resort to pointers' as you think, and could come up with a different and even better solution if you asked your question in a different way. For your case, I would guess pointers are *one* solution, but definitely not the best or only solution.

Comment: @E.Moffat: well, I think I provided all there was to know about the use case. I'm curious if there is any alternative, as not-ghetto as the language allows. Apparently, mine seems to have failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***aim** works because you are assigning `gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().localEulerAngles`to the value of the pointer NOT the pointer.

**aim** does not work because you cannot take the address of a Property. This can only be done on a Field.

Comment: Right. And I need to be able to change the very `gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().localEulerAngles`.